How to have an alt-enter translate into a blank line in a mail merge
I'm trying to use an excel spreadsheet as a data source for a mail merge.  It's not just a simple letter going to multiple recipients but form documents that require a list of names/addresses within the document.  I have a cell in my data source with multiple addresses, separated by an alt-enter and I want that to merge into a word document separated by a blank space.  For example, my data source has a cell with data like this:
John Doe
123 Main Street
Anytown, USA
Mary Smith
456 Johnson Avenue
Anytown USA
Although the data appears with the space between the two entries in the excel cell, when merged into a Word document, it comes through like this:
John Doe
123 Main Street
Anytown, USA
Mary Smith
456 Johnson Avenue
Anytown USA
Is there any way to retain the alt-enter/blank line in the finished merge document?  I've tried formatting the cell as Text and as General - neither works.
Edited to add: I'm on a PC using Microsoft Office 2013 for Word and Excel.
Screenshot of the data in Excel
Screenshot of what it merges like in Word

When I typed my question, my example had each name and address on 3 separate lines - not sure why that didn't remain when I posted.  I'm trying to get 3 lines, blank line, 3 lines.  What I'm getting is 6 consecutive single spaced lines with no separation between the two.

There's a help link in the formatting tools of the editor. Also, you may be looking for a double-space at the end of lines to force another space. For truly specific formatting, a screenshot may be helpful. We do need to know the OS you're working on, the versions of the Office products you're using. Please EDIT your post and add this info.

In case this ever helps anyone else, the solution is to add a space between the alt-enters.  Instead of just hitting alt-enter twice, you hit alt-enter . . . space . . . alt-enter and it will return a blank line between the paragraphs in the merged document.

@Lesliealdrich, please add it as an answer.  24hrs later, you are able to tick it as well.
